# Getting Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [JAX-RS Servlet] in application [ABC_WSv2.1] in LIberty 21.0.0.6

Tags: java, jax-rs, websphere-liberty

we are getting below exception in liberty running in linux box for jax-rs based web service application. But while running in local windows version Liberty (21.0.0.6) , it works fine and no exception thrown. Also we tried various option available in stack overflow and google, nothing worked. can anyone help us on this

```
E SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [JAX-RS Servlet] in application [ABC_WSv2.1]: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.abc.occws.SearchingApplication incompatible with javax.ws.rs.core.Application
```

server.xml configuration below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    
       <featureManager>
        <feature>webProfile-8.0</feature>
        </featureManager>
    
    
    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint" />
  
    <dataSource id="ABCDataSource" jndiName="jdbc/ABCDS" queryTimeout="20m" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <connectionManager agedTimeout="1000m" minPoolSize="1" numConnectionsPerThreadLocal="10"/>
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="OracleLib"/>
    <properties.oracle URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.135.157.5:1565/DOABC_APP" password="xxx" user="xxxx"/>                 
    </dataSource>
                      
     <!-- Define JDBC Drivers -->
  
    <library id="OracleLib">
    <file name="C:/dev/Liberty/ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar"/> 
    </library>
  
    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean" />    
    
    <application id="ABC_WSv2.1" location="C:\Dev\Liberty\ABC_WSv2.1.ear" name="ABC_WSv2.1" type="ear" context-root="/abc-ws">
    <classloader commonLibraryRef="OracleLib"/>
  </application>
  <webContainer uppressHtmlRecursiveErrorOutput="true"/>

</server>
```

Comment: Hi Ambar - the server.xml in the description must be from the working case since it uses Windows-specific paths like "C:/Dev", etc. Could you also post the server.xml for the failing (Linux) case?  It might also help to see the source code for the web.xml and the `SearchingApplication` class.  As Jim alluded to, it is also a possible classloading-related issue - so classloading diagnostics might help, but could you also explain where the `SearchingApplication` class is packaged in the app (i.e. in the WAR's WEB-INF/classes directory, or a jar in WEB-INF/lib or in the EAR, shared library, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

On the surface this looks like this problem is classloader related.  On Windows I suspect you are running this application is isolation whereas on Linux it is running in concert with other things and likely Parent-Last classloading is involved.
I would suggest collecting Liberty classloader trace to see where the affected classes are being loaded from.  Here are some instructions for doing that:  [Liberty Classloader Mustgather](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/mustgather-classloader-problems-websphere-application-server-liberty-profile)

Note:  This is assuming that you are running the same version of your application on both Windows and Linux and in both cases your application class extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application.  If that is not the case then that is certainly causing the problem.